# AFNetworking enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations skipping operation

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I got queue of operations and executing them like this:

```
    [sharedClient setAsJsonClient];
    [sharedClient enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations
                                        progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
//numberOfFinishedOperations = 1 before 1st operation complete block executes
                                        } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {                                            
                                            block(news, games);
                                        }];
```

All the operations has their own completion blocks. Something weird is going on because usually `block(news, games);`is executed before last operation completion block, but not always, like it was dependant on communication speed.

Please help, I'm stuck here.

Comment: This is an issue I couldn't solve myself. I hope it will be fixed when I will migrate my app to AFNetworking 2.

Comment: please let me know if migrating solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue in AFNetworking. It's possibly fixed in AFNetworking2 but I'm not sure of that.